# Path is added multiple times to result array unexpectedly

Tags: bash

I am on macOS, and for the sake of being able to debug with VS Code, I installed `bash` 4 via `homebrew`.

I am developing a script that is supposed to result in an array of all *files* of a certain path.

My issue is that with a certain folder tree I am testing it, one file 3 levels deep gets added 4 times even though it exists only once. I am sure I am overlooking something that I cannot see...

Here's the tree

```
.
├── fetchProjects.sh
├── foo
│   └── bar
│       └── buzz
│           └── foo.file
├── test1
└── test2
```

Here's the script …:

```bash
#!/opt/homebrew/bin/bash

declare -a files=()

fetch_folder_content () {
    echo "Current path is: $1"
    subfolders="$(ls $1)"
    echo "Relative paths are: $subfolders"
    for subfolder in $subfolders; do
        declare -a subfolders=()
        this_path="$1/$subfolder"
        echo "This path: $this_path"
        if test -d $this_path; then
            fetch_folder_content $this_path
        fi
        if test -f $this_path; then
            echo "Appending $subfolder
     to array"
            files[${#files[@]}]=$this_path
        fi
    done
}

fetch_folder_content "."

echo "Found files:"
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

… resulting in the following array:

```
Found files:
./fetchProjects.sh
./foo/bar/buzz/foo.file
./foo/bar/buzz/foo.file
./foo/bar/buzz/foo.file
./foo/bar/buzz/foo.file
./test1
./test2
```

Comment: Don't use `ls`. `subfolders=(*/)` will get the names of subdirectories safely and correctly.

Comment: `$subfolders` is equivalent to `${subfolders[0]}`; you need `for subfolder in "${subfolders[@]}"; do` at the very least to iterate over *all* subfolders.

Comment: `find . -type f` would be a bit shorter

Comment: Using `find . -type f` is actually a very good suggestion... I could not make the other suggestions work, which is probably a me-problem...

Comment: Since you are using a modern version of `bash`, you can simply iterate over `./**/*` and add the regular files to your result. (This enables turning on the `globstar` option.)

Comment: hmmmm .... while looping over the contents of the (scalar) variable `subfolders` (`subfolders="$(ls $1)"` / `for subfolder in $subfolders`) you go and redefine `subfolders` as an empty array (`declare -a subfolders=()`); I haven't tried to debug the script but this one instance of changing the type and contents of a variable while looping over the contents of said variable ... likely does not bode well for the final outcome

Comment: your script contains a lot of `echo` calls that should serve as a pseudo-debug call tree ... have you stepped through that set of (echo) outputs to verify you're generating the expected set of messages?

Comment: also consider the variables you've defined in the function are (as currently code) declared as 'global' which means all instances of the (nested) function calls are modifying/using the same single copy of these variables (ie, subordinate function calls are changing the values of the parents' variables) which can lead to unexpected behavior; consider defining all such variables as 'local' (eg, `local subfolders="$(ls $1)"`; see the `local` builtin)

Comment: I did not know that this was a thing with bash – even though I am familiar with the concept itself from python. TIL. Thanks for educating me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `globstar` option to recursively walk a directory.

```
shopt -s globstar

files=()

for f in ./**/*; do
    test -f "$f" && files+=("$f")
done
```

As you are on macOS, if you use `zsh` instead, you can filter non-regular files using the glob directory (and you don't need to explicitly enable the recursive glob `**`):

```
files=(./**/*(.))
```

(This applies to *any* machine with `zsh` installed; I only point out macOS because `zsh` has been the default interactive shell for years.)

Answer (score 0):

You are somehow messing up the subfolders variable/array which you do not need at all...

```
#!/opt/homebrew/bin/bash

declare -a files=()

fetch_folder_content () {
    echo "Current path is: $1"
    local p="$1"
    #subfolders="$(ls $1)"
    #echo "Relative paths are: $subfolders"
    for subfolder in $(ls $p); do
        #declare -a subfolders=()
        this_path="$1/$subfolder"
        echo "This path: $this_path"
        if test -d $this_path; then
            fetch_folder_content $this_path
        fi
        if test -f $this_path; then
            echo "Appending $subfolder
             to array"
            files[${#files[@]}]=$this_path
        fi
    done
}

fetch_folder_content "."

echo "Found files:"
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: That yields the same result on my machine, even though you're right in saying that I can loop over `ls $1` directly. I trust you have tried your script with a similar tree? You don't have duplicated entries?

Comment: Ah another idea, also avoid the `$1`positional which gets overwritten on the next fetch_folder_content recursion...

Comment: Which is what I want, right? I want to check the next subpath which is why I am calling the function with the new parameter–or am I overlooking something here?

Comment: yes, but assign the $1 to a variable might help, see edit

Comment: recursion in bash shell is a bit tricky, I added a `local` before the `p=$1`

Comment: Yeah, didn't know about `local` in bash so far, thanks for educating me.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.